# SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Already present: The column already exists - Yugabyte DB

Tags: sql, alter-table, yugabytedb

SQL Alter script:

```
alter table table_name ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS chk_col jsonb not null 
DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb;
```

In this script, I am getting "ERROR: Already present: The column already exists" but the column chk_col is not present in the table.

If I remove DB and then create again the same script is executed successfully.

How do I correct it without removing the database?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more your setup ?
What version are you using ?
Are there needed other steps to reproduce ?
I can't reproduce in 2.7.1.1:

```sql
yugabyte=# create database fshije
yugabyte=# \c fshije

fshije=# create table table_name(id bigint);
fshije=# alter table table_name ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS chk_col jsonb not null DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb;
fshije=# \d table_name
               Table "public.table_name"
 Column  |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |   Default   
---------+--------+-----------+----------+-------------
 id      | bigint |           |          | 
 chk_col | jsonb  |           | not null | '{}'::jsonb
```

Comment: Version is 2.7.1.1.

No other steps are required to reproduce this, we are running this alter query as a migration script in our env.

Though, I got this error in local after running alter script(add column, drop column) few times.

Comment: Can you send a script to reproduce this somehow ? Did you hit it once or multiple times ? Because it looks similar to this issue that was fixed in 2.7.1.1 https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/5543

Comment: Yes, getting the same issue that you have mentioned above. First I ran an incorrect alter script then the correct one and got this issue. How do I correct it without creating the database again?

steps to reproduce:
1. alter table table_name ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS chk_col2 boolean not null
2. alter table table_name ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS chk_col2 boolean not null default false

in 2nd step getting this error.

Comment: You can try by dropping the table. What are you getting with `\d table_name` ?